# postgres query shows error

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is my postgres query to do inner join on the same table itself.. But the below query shows error before the inner join.

```
select org.id, org.name, org.lft, org.rgt, tmp.id, tmp.name, tmp.lft, tmp.rgt from organization_organization as org WHERE (org.id IN (62)) 
INNER JOIN organization_organization as tmp ON (org.tree_id=tmp.tree_id) 
WHERE (tmp.id = org.id) OR (org.lft > tmp.lft AND org.rgt < tmp.rgt)
```

Comment: You have two where clauses. Merge first where with the second and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `JOIN` syntax is incorrect. `INNER JOIN` keyword comes before `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT  org.id, 
        org.name, 
        org.lft, 
        org.rgt, 
        tmp.id, 
        tmp.name, 
        tmp.lft, 
        tmp.rgt 
FROM    organization_organization AS org 
        INNER JOIN organization_organization AS tmp 
            ON org.tree_id = tmp.tree_id
WHERE   org.id IN (62)
        AND 
        (
            (tmp.id = org.id) 
            OR (org.lft > tmp.lft AND org.rgt < tmp.rgt)
        )
```

Comment: HI @John, it works but I got duplicate rows.. Is that we have to use distinct keyword?

Comment: @AvinashRaj by duplicate, you mean all values are the same for all columns? if so, you can simply use `DISTINCT` inside your `SELECT` statement. eg `SELECT DISTINCT org.id, ......`

Answer (score 2):

Your Join syntax is not correct and your code has two where clause.In inner joining your query return same row multiple times, if any column value repeats, to avoid this duplication you have to use DISTINCT.

```
select 
    distinct on(org.id)
    org.id, 
    org.name, 
    org.lft, 
    org.rgt, 
    tmp.id, 
    tmp.name, 
    tmp.lft, 
    tmp.rgt 
from 
    organization_organization as org 
INNER JOIN 
    organization_organization as tmp 
ON 
    org.tree_id=tmp.tree_id
WHERE 
    org.id IN (62)
and
    (
        tmp.id = org.id
OR 
        org.lft > tmp.lft AND org.rgt < tmp.rgt
    )
group by org.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Place 'WHERE (org.id IN (62))' in second WHERE clause

```
select org.id, org.name, org.lft, org.rgt, tmp.id, tmp.name, tmp.lft, 
tmp.rgt from organization_organization as org 
INNER JOIN organization_organization as tmp ON (org.tree_id=tmp.tree_id) 
WHERE ((tmp.id = org.id) OR (org.lft > tmp.lft AND org.rgt < tmp.rgt))
and (org.id IN (62))
```